# Converting a script into GUI using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I really need help, I have written a script that implements a flow equation. The problem is that i would love to convert this to a GUI, I am a student and i am meant to submit this assignment anytime soon, i don't have time for learning Tkinter now but i will surely learn it next month. the script below:

```
print ("this program measures gas flowrate in pipes with effect of elevation, making use of USCS unit")
e=2.718
Tb=520
Pb=14.7
f=float(input("Friction factor,f: "))
P1=float(input("upstream pressure,P1: "))
P2=float(input("downstream pressure,P2: "))
G=float(input("gas gravity,G: "))
Tf=float(input("average gas flowing temperature,Tf: "))
L=float(input("pipe line segment,L: "))
Z=float(input("gas compressibility factor at flowing temperature,Z: "))
D=float(input("pipe inside diameter,D: "))
H1=float(input("upstream elevation,H1: "))
H2=float(input("downstream elevation,H2: "))
s=float((0.0375*G)*((H2-H1)/(Tf*Z)))
j=float((e**s-1)/s)
Le=float(L*j)
F=float(2/f**0.5)
Q=38.77*F*(Tb/Pb)*((P1**2-(e**s*P2**2))/(G*Tf*Le*Z))**0.5*D**2.5
print(j);
print(s);
print(Q);
```

Thanks alot for assistance

Comment: What would you like to have as GUI? The input and output?

Comment: Sounds like you could use [EasyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: So, you're asking us to do your homework for you? That's not what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: `i don't have time for learning Tkinter now but i will surely learn it next month` this is  a very bad approach to take in a programming class (or most classes, for that matter).

Comment: Thanks all. It is not I dont want to learn it, I am still striving along everyday learning python first..

Comment: Could you please link me to a good online resource

Answer (score 2):

First, import tkinter and create the main object:

```
import Tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
```

Then create inputs that will go in the main window. For each input, create a label and an entry for the input:

Example:

```
L1 = tk.Label(master, text="friction factor, f: ")
L1.pack()
L1.grid(row=0, column=0)

E1 = tk.Entry(master, bd =5)
E1.pack()
E1.grid(row=0, column=1)

# .... all other labels and input entries
# And a label for the result:

result = tk.Label(master)
result.pack()
```

Then, get all values from the entries to variables, for example:

```
f = float(E1.get())
```

Add a button to press for calculation:

```
button = tk.Button(master, text='Calculate', command=calculate)
button.pack()

# calculate is a function that you will define, that gets all values from the input and returns the final value. Send also the result label to the function to change the text of the result label.

def calculate(result, f, .....):
    # Your calculating algorithem
    output = "j: " + str(j) + ", Q: "+ str(Q) + ", s: "+str(s)
    result.config(text=output)
```

In the end of your code, you will have this line that runs the window:

```
master.mainloop()
```

If you need further explanation, please write.

Comment: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) recommends against wildcard imports.

Comment: @BryanOakley I know, it's a bad habit, but he is not really looking for the best solution - just a one that would work.

Comment: If you know it's a bad habit, don't teach others to do it. This is a person who knows nothing about tkinter, and the first thing you're doing is teaching them a bad habit.

Comment: @BryanOakley You're right, I am taking your advice.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, i just bought a book to learn Tkinter. I appreciate your help. Could you please link me to a good online resource?